# Using boost spirit parser for in-line editing and autocompletion prompting

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I am trying to design a server app which will read a command line over a socket stream (one character at a time). Obviously the simple way is to read characters up to the EOL and execute the command contained in the receive buffer.

Instead, I want to have it so that when a user starts entering a command line and then enters "?", the app will generate a list of all the parameters which are syntactically correct from that point in the parsing of the command line (this is similar to the way it is in some embedded devices that I have seen, like Cisco and Netscreen routers).

For example,

```
$ set interface ?
```

would display

```
> set interface [option] -- displays information about the specified interface.
>
> [option] must be one of the following:
>   address [ip-addr]
>   port [port-no]
>   protocol [tcp|udp]
```

So basically, I would need to know where we were in the grammar, and what symbols are expected from that point forward.

It would also be nice if it could support simple line editing commands (BS, DEL, insert, left-arrow, right-arrow), and maybe even up-arrow/down-arrow for command history.

Can this be done using the boost spirit parser?

EDIT:

Simply put: Is there a simple way to create a boost spirit parser which (in addition to having a set of rules), immediately executes an action anytime '?' is encountered on the input stream (without having to explicitly encode the token '?' into the rules)?

Comment: This question is overly broad. I assume it is because you (unwittingly?) mixing several abstraction levels. I suggest you break it down, because, e.g. emulating terminal style editing has nothing to do with parsing input. The answer the question as is, is "Yes".

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I've added a more specific statement of the question at the end.